# How to use HTML/CSS to group images into a grid with circular crop

Tags: html, css

I have four images, I want them to form a collage like the image below: all four arranged into a 2x2 grid, and the grid itself cropped to a cricle.

What is the HTML/CSS needed to achieve this effect, as in the image below?

```
<div>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
<img src=""></img>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Get your image arranged in a square like that, and then apply border-radius to the parent element ...

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: A little confused as to why the question was closed: it was clearly written enough. I took the time to craft a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/kop34gac/

Answer (score 2):

**Sets the display to a grid layout with two columns (grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)). You can adjust the width and height of the .collage element as per your desired size  and if you need some space between images then use for a gap between the images (grid-gap: 10px).**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <style>
      .collage {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        /* grid-gap: 10px; */
        width: 400px; /* Adjust as needed */
        height: 400px; /* Adjust as needed */
        border:2px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .collage img {
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="collage">
        <img src="" alt="Image 1" />
        <img src="" alt="Image 2" />
        <img src="" alt="Image 3" />
        <img src="" alt="Image 4" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The .collage class also has a border-radius property set to 50% to create the circular shape. The overflow property is set to hidden to hide any overflow from the circular cropping.

The .collage img selector sets the images to fill their respective grid cells using object-fit: cover. They will maintain their aspect ratio while covering the entire available space in each grid cell.

Make sure to replace the src attribute of each  element with the correct image source URLs.

By applying this HTML and CSS code, the four images will be arranged in a 2x2 grid, and the grid itself will be cropped into a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Solution requires 3 steps:

- Get your images the same size
- Arrange them in a 2x2 grid
- Clip the border of that grid to a circle.

You can achieve each with a `<div>` and CSS to match:

- To get images the same size and in a container: use explicit height, width, and [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- To get the 2x2 grid, use [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout)
- To clip the grid to a circular border, use [CSS Border Radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Complete example in the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kop34gac/

With this result:

[image]